# NetworkManager doesn't read a new domain in ifcfg-eth0

Tags: rhel, networkmanager, resolv.conf

I'm using a RHEL 6.7 and I need to add a new DOMAIN to resolv.conf that is generated by NetworkManager.

In /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 there are already other domains that are in resolv.conf also. But, after adding a domain and rebooted network and NetworkManager services, the new domain doesn't appear in resolv.conf.